# Error: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> in python forloop on DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe x:

```
     T
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   NaN
3   4.0
4   5.0
5   6.0
6   7.0
```

I want to multiply 2 to cummax if value is not NaN

Code written:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    print(i)
    if math.isnan(x["T"].iloc[i]):
        continue
    else:
        x["T"].iloc[i] = x["T"].iloc[:i+1].cummax() * 2
```

But I am getting the error:

```
No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Desired Output:

```
     T
0   2.0
1   4.0
2   NaN
3   16.0
4   32.0
5   64.0
6   128.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cummax` return a **series**, but you need just the last value of this series:

```
x["T"].iloc[i] = x["T"].iloc[:i+1].cummax().iloc[-1] * 2
```

or simply less convoluted:

```
x["T"].iloc[i] = x["T"].iloc[:i+1].max() * 2
```